# IPython Notebook Kernel Periodically Dies

Tags: ipython, enthought, jupyter-notebook

Running Linux Mint 13 Maya (64-bit)

On both epd 7.3.2 (academic) and Canopy, when running notebook the kernel dies periodically.  I get a pop-up that allows me to restart the kernel.  I get this in the terminal window:

```
$ ipython notebook --pylab inline --notebook-dir=***
[NotebookApp] Using existing profile dir: u'*****.config/ipython/profile_default'
[NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from *****
[NotebookApp] The IPython Notebook is running at: http://127.0.0.1:8888/
[NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels.
[NotebookApp] Using MathJax from CDN: http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js
[NotebookApp] Kernel started: 5425f0fa-38cc-4e1e-a39d-736d3ac935e3
[NotebookApp] Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:33939
[NotebookApp] Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:52824
[NotebookApp] Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:54440
[IPKernelApp] To connect another client to this kernel, use:
[IPKernelApp] --existing kernel-5425f0fa-38cc-4e1e-a39d-736d3ac935e3.json
[NotebookApp] Kernel 5425f0fa-38cc-4e1e-a39d-736d3ac935e3 failed to respond to heartbeat
[NotebookApp] Kernel started: dc484a8e-c822-46b1-bc6d-a1e019a67258
[NotebookApp] Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:45376
[NotebookApp] Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:54515
[NotebookApp] Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:51380
[IPKernelApp] To connect another client to this kernel, use:
[IPKernelApp] --existing kernel-dc484a8e-c822-46b1-bc6d-a1e019a67258.json
[NotebookApp] Kernel dc484a8e-c822-46b1-bc6d-a1e019a67258 failed to respond to heartbeat
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue looks similar to https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/2824. It might be addressed in newer IPython versions, or you can find suggestions there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using the latest Enthought Canopy Express (ex-EPD Free). To fix that, I just upgraded IPython to 0.13.1, and it stopped dying and began to work smoothly as with my other (standard own made) install of IPython.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, when I reboot system, for importing anything like sklearn or skimage it gives massage like "The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically." Then it does not restart at all, I had to reinstall canopy and then install all the packages i need.
Is there any way to repair canopy then reinstall?
Why this is happening most often